# Modifying Flink ElasticSearchSink to not use types mapping

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-flink

I've run into some problems with a Flink implementation that's using Flink 1.9 and ElasticSearch 7.3.2. My pipe fetches events from Kafka and then writes them to ElasticSearch (after some processing). However I keep getting the following warning.

`WARN  org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient                           - request [POST http://IP:PORT/_bulk?timeout=1m] returned 1 warnings: [299 Elasticsearch-7.3.2-1c1faf1 "[types removal] Specifying types in bulk requests is deprecated."]`

And the warning is quite clear, however, what I'm wondering is that it's possible to handle this warning in the ElasticSearch sink?

I'm using the **flink-connector-elasticsearch6_2.11** and this is how I've implemented the following Sink function:

```
public class ElasticsearchEventSink implements ElasticsearchSinkFunction<HashMap> {

    public IndexRequest createIndexRequest(HashMap<String, Object> event) {

        OffsetDateTime currentDate = OffsetDateTime.now();
        String dateString = String.format("%s-%02d-%02d", currentDate.getYear(), currentDate.getMonthValue(), currentDate.getDayOfMonth());
        String indexName = "events";

        return Requests.indexRequest()
                .index(indexName + '-' + dateString)
                .type("_doc")
                .source(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void process(HashMap event, RuntimeContext runtimeContext, RequestIndexer indexer) {
        indexer.add(createIndexRequest(event));
    }
}
```

Thankful for any help!